# Como resolver a exceção CSharp_EIDMW_ERR_PINREF_NOT_FOUND_get

Tags: c#

Eu tenho um projeto em C# que utiliza a biblioteca do Gov para aceder a dados de um smartcard (cartão de cidadão), a Biblioteca chama-se pteidlib_dotnet, que podem encontrar [aqui](https://github.com/rmpt/CCReader/releases)

Eu necessito de criar uma funcionalidade que me permite assinar digitalmente documentos pdf com o Cartao de cidadao, e penso ter o codigo correto (como está no manual que vem com as bibliotecas, que podem encontrar [aqui em pdf](https://www.autenticacao.gov.pt/documents/10179/12134/Manual+do+SDK+%E2%80%93%20Middleware+do+Cart%C3%A3o+de+Cidad%C3%A3o.pdf/e920eccd-7fc2-4632-83df-c7bef469cc5e)), o problema agora, é que quando tento assinar a biblioteca lança uma exceção qual eu  não consigo encontrar a solução na internet para resolver.

Já pesquisei bastante e penso que o problema esteja relacionado com o metodo init 
 da biblioteca que não reconhece o nome do meu smartcard reader, mas ainda assim não consigo resolver (função init penso que é chamada internamente, pelo que no meu codigo não a chamo.)

Queria vir aqui então pedir ajuda caso alguem saiba porque da exceção.

Inner Exception - **em pt.portugal.eid.pteidlib_dotNetPINVOKE.SWIGExceptionHelper..ctor() em pt.portugal.eid.pteidlib_dotNetPINVOKE..cctor()**

Message - **O inicializador de tipo para 'pt.portugal.eid.pteidlib_dotNetPINVOKE' accionou uma excepção.**

StackTrace - **em pt.portugal.eid.pteidlib_dotNetPINVOKE.PTEID_ReaderSet_instance() em pt.portugal.eid.PTEID_ReaderSet.instance()**

Codigo:

```
private static void AssinarFicheiros(string[] ficheiros)
{
    ficheiros[0] = @"c:\teste\fich1.pdf";
    //ficheiros[1] = @"c:\teste\fich2.pdf";
    if (ficheiros is null)
        return;

    string destino = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\ficheiros_assinados.zip";

    string localizacao = "local";
    string razao = "razao";
    int pagina = 1;
    int sector = 2;
    bool isLandscape = false; // TODO: Pode não estar correcto para todos os casos, visto que não conseguimos indentificar se os documentos estão na horizontal.

    try
    {
        using (PTEID_ReaderSet readerSet = PTEID_ReaderSet.instance())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < readerSet.readerCount(); i++)
            {
                using (PTEID_ReaderContext context = readerSet.getReaderByNum(unchecked((uint)i)))
                {
                    if (context.isCardPresent())
                    {
                        using (PTEID_EIDCard card = context.getEIDCard())
                        {
                            using (PTEID_PDFSignature signature = new PTEID_PDFSignature())
                            {
                                if (ficheiros.Length == 1)
                                {
                                    signature.addToBatchSigning(@"c:\teste\fich1.pdf");
                                    signature.enableSmallSignatureFormat();
                                    signature.enableTimestamp();

                                    // Aqui lança a exceção CSharp_EIDMW_ERR_PINREF_NOT_FOUND_get quando tenta executar esta linha de código.
                                    card.SignPDF(signature, pagina, sector, isLandscape, localizacao, razao, destino);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //card.SignPDF(destino, ficheiros, unchecked((uint)ficheiros.Length));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString());
    }
}
```

Se alguem me puder guiar na direção onde possa encontrar a solução já ajudaria bastante.

Agradeço desde já qualquer resposta.

Comment: Adicione também os detalhes da exceção, como message, stacktrace e inner exception.

Comment: A postagem já foi atualizada, obrigado!

Comment: Não é relacionado ao seu `destino`? O arquivo existe e ele vai, de fato, conseguir incluir o documento assinado dentro de um `.zip`?

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado, vi que o manual "Middleware, continha um erro! O destino deve ser uma pasta e não um arquivo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neste caso, o erro encontra-se na documentação, e a solução encontrada, foi apenas a remoção da extensão do ficheiro destino, pois o destino precisa ser uma pasta!!!